# How to design python code for telegram (telebot lib)?

Tags: python, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

I am developing a telegram bot, and I have many handlers for responses from the user.

Since there are many handlers and many different dialogs are also possible. I moved some of the handlers into different classes (Dialogs)

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot(tg_api_key)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['buy_something'])

def buy(message):

    from dialogs.buy_something
    import Buy_Dialog
    w = Buy_Dialog(bot, message)
```

and:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['sell_something'])

def sell(message):
    from dialogs.sell_something 
    import Sell_Dialog
    w = Sell_Dialog(bot, message)
```

Inside the dialog classes I can send questions to the user and get answers from them by using:

```
self.m = self.bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Some question")
self.bot.register_next_step_handler(self.m, self.enter_your_name)
```

But now I need to get from user callback from button click:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def button_click_yes_or_no(self, call):
```

So I can catch them only from `main.py`, not inside the dialog.

How to redesign code to get clear logic and code with the ability to catch `button_callback`?

Answer (score 0):

maybe the function can't see your variable try to make your variable global in the beginning of the code :

```
global your variable, another variable
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot catch callbacks from inside the class instance.

But you can follow the same logic as for commands: create a decorated general function for catch all calls and pass each one to proper class instance based on call's content (`call.data` or `call.message.chat.id`).